# Can ActiveRecord use a proxy to access the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, heroku, proximo

I need to access a database that requires whitelisted IPs. In order to have a static IP I am using Proximo AddOn on Heroku. It allows me to use a proxy for outbound connections.

Can I use that proxy to access a database? I searched on ActiveRecord documentation but I couldnt find any reference.

Comment: It is possible to use a SOCKS proxy (read on the documentation that Proximo can be used as a SOCKS5 proxy) to route a database connection, but I could not find an option in the pg gem (the connection manager rails uses for postgresql) to specify a proxy.

Comment: I can use any gem, actually it will be a mysql database

Comment: I didn' t find any mention of proxy support on the mysql and mysql2 gems. I am sorry I don't know the first thing of mysql.